# Hibernate Select top row for each group

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, group-by, hql

Hi is there a way where we can do this via HQL??
where it returns me list of DTO instead of list of Object Class.
My sql query is

```
select * from readings   join  
        (select max(signal) as signal,sender as sr ,receiver as rc from readings  group by readings.sender,readings.receiver)a 
    on  
    a.signal=readings.signal and 
    a.sr=readings.sender and 
    a.rc=readings.receiver
```

Here is my DTO/Bean/Pojo class

```
public class Readings implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String sender;
    private String major;
    private String minor;
    private int signal;
    private BigDecimal power;
    private BigDecimal temperature;
    private String battery;
    private String receiver;
    private Date createdDatetime;..

and getters and setters ...
```

Which in HQL is

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(com.XYZ..Readings.class)
                        .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.max("signal"))
                       .add(Projections.groupProperty("sender"))
                        .add(Projections.groupProperty("receiver")));


List<Readings>  br=(List<Readings>)cr.list();
```

This fails at the last line, trying to cast Object to Readings class.

Comment: So, `Readings` is a DTO and not an entity?

Comment: Please post the code for the `Readings` class.

Comment: DTO added above ...